# break statement for 2d list

Tags: python-3.x, list, break

I am new to Python and have an assignment to extract images and labels from a list. I have a database of images (Red,Green, Blue, Yellow, etc.). The images are in the first column whereas the corresponding labels(Red, Green, Blue, etc are in the second column). I am trying to write a code where let's say I want to run through the loop and extract the first yellow image and break out of the program. The code as it stands right now breaks out of the if loop but goes all the way till the end and updates the i values and the wrong image is extracted. I tried putting multiple break statements as well as break statements in different positions but it doesn't seem to work out for me. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
rows = len(IMAGE_LIST)
columns = len(IMAGE_LIST)
   for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
         if IMAGE_LIST[j][1] == "Yellow":

         sel_image = IMAGE_LIST[j][0]

         sel_label = IMAGE_LIST[j][1]

        break

 print(j)

 plt.imshow(IMAGE_LIST[j][0])

 print(IMAGE_LIST[j][1])
```

Comment: I don't see where do you use the value of `j`, the second loop index. Also please describe the shape of `IMAGE_LIST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your 2d list has the structure `[['image1.png', 'blue'],  ['image2.jpeg', 'yellow'], ...]` as specified in the OP, you don't need a nested for-loop structure. Once you find the image with the desired color, the program will break and the name and color will be set using the global `i` variable initialized in the for-loop. Please let me know if this works or if your data structure is more complex than this.

```
rows = len(IMAGE_LIST)
# columns = len(IMAGE_LIST) # not needed given my assumptions
for i in range(rows):
  if IMAGE_LIST[i][1].lower() == "yellow": # ignore casing to deal with possible user labeling errors
    break # index i will stay in scope
sel_image, sel_label = IMAGE_LIST[i] # unpacks the current row into variables

print('index', i)
print('color', sel_label)

plt.imshow(sel_image)
```